# Can I reduce this JQ expression

Tags: jq

Here is my input:

```
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
lava1    pts/0    157.48.149.102   05:03   31.00s  0.31s  0.31s -bash
azureuse pts/1    157.48.149.102   07:26    0.00s  0.07s  0.05s w
```

And, if I supply this JQ, I get the results I want:

```
jq -sRre 'split("\n") |
map(split(" ") |
map(
    select(
        (. | length) > 0)
    )
) |
map(
    select(
        (.|length) > 0
    )
) |
.[0] as $cols
| .[1:]
| map(. as $row
  | $cols
  | with_entries({ "key": .value,"value": $row[.key]})
)'
```

yields:

```json
[
  {
    "USER": "lava1",
    "TTY": "pts/0",
    "FROM": "157.48.149.102",
    "LOGIN@": "05:03",
    "IDLE": "31.00s",
    "JCPU": "0.31s",
    "PCPU": "0.31s",
    "WHAT": "-bash"
  },
  {
    "USER": "azureuse",
    "TTY": "pts/1",
    "FROM": "157.48.149.102",
    "LOGIN@": "07:26",
    "IDLE": "0.00s",
    "JCPU": "0.07s",
    "PCPU": "0.05s",
    "WHAT": "w"
  }
]
```

but I am pretty sure it's more verbose/less optimal than it can be because I do 2 splits and then have to filter out the empty arrays I get.

When I try to simplify with
`jq -R 'split("\\s+"; "g") '`

I get

```
[
  "USER",
  "TTY",
  "FROM",
  "LOGIN@",
  "IDLE",
  "JCPU",
  "PCPU",
  "WHAT"
]
[
  "lava1",
  "pts/0",
  "157.48.149.102",
  "05:03",
  "31.00s",
  "0.31s",
  "0.31s",
  "-bash"
]
[
  "azureuse",
  "pts/1",
  "157.48.149.102",
  "07:26",
  "0.00s",
  "0.07s",
  "0.05s",
  "w"
]
```

Which isn't quite an array, so the title/column portion of my expression no longer works and I am not sure how I take the above and turn it back into an array, so the final part of the expression works.

**The question:** How can I reduce this JQ expression and command to its bare minimum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I reduce this JQ expression and command to its bare minimum?

Here you go, run it with the `-R` flag only:

```
def s: [splits(" +")];
[s as $k | inputs | [$k, s] | transpose | map({(.[0]): .[1]}) | add]
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Sq645_nIB4D)</sup>

Most whitespace is for readability, you can further shorten it by removing them.

Answer (score 1):

how i would split the table:

```
$ cat input.txt |
  jq -R -s 'split("\n")|map(select(length > 0)|[splits("\\s+"; "x")])' 

[["USER","TTY","FROM","LOGIN@","IDLE","JCPU","PCPU","WHAT"],
 ["lava1","pts/0","157.48.149.102","05:03","31.00s","0.31s","0.31s","-bash"],
 ["azureuse","pts/1","157.48.149.102","07:26","0.00s","0.07s","0.05s","w"]]
```

then

```bash
cat input.txt |
  jq -R -s 'split("\n")|map(select(length > 0)|[splits("\\s+"; "x")])' |
  jq '.[0] as $cols|.[1:]|map(. as $row|$cols|with_entries({"key": .value, "value":$row[.key]}))'


# using only one jq command:
jq -R -s 'split("\n") | map(select(length > 0) | [splits("\\s+"; "x")])
  | .[0] as $cols | .[1:] | map(. as $row|$cols
  | with_entries({"key": .value,"value": $row[.key]}))' input.txt
```

Comment: im not sure reduce makes sense here but let me know if im wrong

Comment: This is slightly simpler as it's 1 less `select` statement.